# how to use JQuery Vector Map and Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

i am trying to visualize my django model data of six columns on a jqueryVector Map and i dont know how to do that. i need an answer as soon as possible.

```
$(function() {
        $('#map').vectorMap({
          map: 'world_mill_en',
          series: {
            regions: [{
              values: gdpData,
              scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
              normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
            }]
          },
          backgroundColor: '#eef3f7',
          onLabelShow: function(e, el, code) {
            el.html(el.html() + ' (GDP - ' + gdpData[code] + ')');
          }
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular way to access Django model data inside HTML or Javascript is through [Django's templating system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/templates/).

First, you need to place your data inside a [template variable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/templates/#variables):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {
        'data': [1,2,3],
    })
```

Then, you can access the data in your template:

```
$(function() {
        $('#map').vectorMap({
          map: 'world_mill_en',
          series: {
            regions: [{
              values: [{% for value in data %}{{value}}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}],
              scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
              normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
            }]
          },
          backgroundColor: '#eef3f7',
          onLabelShow: function(e, el, code) {
            el.html(el.html() + ' (GDP - ' + gdpData[code] + ')');
          }
        });
      });
```